# Using matlab to solve system of algebraic equations, got no answers

Tags: matlab

I used the following matlab code to solve a system of  algebraic equations, but I got no answer.

clear; clc; close all;

syms x y z u

eqns = [2*x + 1 == 2*u*x, 4*y == 2*u*y, 6*z == 2*u*z, x^2 + y^2 +z^2 == 1];

S = solve(eqns,[x y z u]);

S.u

### the result says:

ans =

### Empty sym: 0-by-1

But there should be answers, to see the answers, please refer to an MIT calculus course:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nDuS5uQ7-lo&list=PLkcAPvx7T8bBOOuDcxZE_sdTchjQcTyM-&index=29

So , what is wrong?

Comment: Try `solve(2*x+1==2*u*x, 4*y==2*u*y, 6*z==2*u*z, x^2+y^2+z^2==1)` instead

Comment: That works! ${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Actually the problem was your `eqns` in the fourth equation `x^2 + y^2 +z^2 ==1` gets interpreted by Matlab as two different elements, `x^2 + y^2` and `z^2==1`. It needs a space before `z^2` : `x^2 + y^2 + z^2 ==1`

Comment: Thank you! @David It works! And as you said, the space caused the problem,   that is really subtle.